# Magento issue with order increment ID

Tags: magento-1.9

I have around 10 stores, not much traffic on application. I know the quick fix to this issue by making modification in database. But I get this issue several time after 2-3 months and I am not sure why it occurs.

Exception:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '50011893' for key
>   'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID'' in
>   /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Can anyone help me to understand the reason? so that I can provide a permanent fix to my client.

Comment: I think some duplicate entry with the sales_order table in some foreign keey

Comment: I need the scenario if you have faced anytime.